# Suhosin.memory_limit does not allow PHP to use more memory

Tags: memory, php

I have a server where PHP memory_limit is 256M. Some scripts need more memory and does a ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); but since Suhosin is installed and activated, I find this in log file

```
Sep 17 14:06:42 www-01 suhosin[28934]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 536870912 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker '127.0.0.1', file '/xxx/generate_docs.php', line 45)
```

But suhosin is configured with

```
suhosin.memory_limit = 2048M
```

Both PHP memory_limit and suhosin.memory_limit values are confirmed by phpinfo(). Why PHP can't ask for more memory with this setup?

This script run fine for any memory limit value under 256M, but for a higher value I got the error and memory_limit don't change.

```
<?php
echo ini_get('memory_limit') . "<br>";
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
echo ini_get('memory_limit') . "<br>";
echo ini_get('suhosin.memory_limit') . "<br>";
echo "end<br>";
```

the output is

```
256M
256M
2048M
end
```

Comment: As exmplained in the documentation the suhosin value is a hard limit, while php's value is a soft limit.

See: http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.memory_limit

Comment: My question is : if suhosin HARD limit is 2048, why I can't set php memory SOFT limit higher than 256M ? There is a clear bug when I set suhosin limit to 2048M. See my answer below.

Comment: Because the you can't set a soft limit higher than a hard limit *by definition*

Comment: The HARD limit is 2048M, but the SOFT limit can't be higher than 256M. 2048M is greater than 256M or event 512M, in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alleluia. Asking a question help me to find the problem.

By setting suhosin.memory_limit to 1024 (2048 was for testing with an edge value), it run, and my script tells me

```
256M
512M
1024M
end
```

Same problem as 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276212/php-settings-memory-limits-1024m-does-not-work/16854780#16854780
(same server, by the way)

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand why that wasn't working with your previous `suhosin.memory_limit` value of `2048M`.. Could you please explain? PHP `memory_limit` default is `256M`, you're trying to set it to `512M`, which is still **lower** than `suhosin.memory_limit 2048M` limit, so that should have worked.